# The UI search bar disappears when clicked( possibly NSLayoutConstraint issue)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar, nslayoutconstraint, uisearchcontroller

A quick question, for what should've been an easy implementation.

Im trying to implement a UISearchcontroller and the UIsearchbar property when trying to customize it and set constraints behaves properly appears perfect but the minute i click on the search bar it resets its constraints to nil(guessing based on visual debugger).

[**Before clicking**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9nhG.jpg)

and here is the second image which shows what happens when clicked

[**After clicking**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCris.jpg)

Ive been trying to do this for a day now.

**Context:**  My Main VC is a collection view and another button.

below is the search view specific code, I tried isolating the issue in a playground file and noticed issue **starts** when i add constraints to it.

```
 var searchController:UISearchController!

 private func setupSearchView(){
    
    let viewController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    viewController.delegate = self
    let bar = viewController.searchBar
    bar.delegate = self
    bar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    bar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    bar.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    bar.searchTextField.textColor = .darkGray
    bar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
    bar.showsCancelButton = false
    bar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
    bar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
    bar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    bar.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    bar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    guard let customFont = UIFont(name: "Poppins-SemiBold", size: 14.0) else {
        fatalError("""
           Failed to load the "CustomFont-Light" font.
           Make sure the font file is included in the project and the font name is spelled correctly.
           """
        )}
    bar.searchTextField.font=customFont
    self.searchController = viewController
    self.view.addSubview(bar)
    bar.isHidden = true
    
  }

func setupContstraints() {
    //NSLayoutConstrainst
    let searchBar:UISearchBar=searchController!.searchBar
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        searchButton!.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -30),
        searchButton!.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 30),
        searchButton!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        searchButton!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        //search bar
         searchBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
        searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 30),

        searchBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170.0),
        searchBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0)]

       )
```

**Update:**
When i gave the search bar fixed width and height(*not ideal for different device size*) it now appears with the width and height but doesn't obey the top anchor constraint.

**[See current image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqF1L.jpg)**

*also updated the snippet with current constraints*

Comment: So where do you want your search bar to be exactly then? Can you describe it in words?

Comment: yes my bad, i tried to make a few changes to check whether it works, i got rid of the centreX constraints but its still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Give a fixed width and height value for your "SearchBar" object. It will probably be fixed.

It may take up as much width as the cursor when clicked.

**Comment out or delete the 2 lines below while giving a fixed height and width for the searchBar.**

```
searchBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 50),
searchBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -100)
```

Comment: I updated it, now the uisearch bar is visible but doesn't obey the top anchor constraint.

Comment: Convert the "SearchBar" and "SearchButton" objects into a UIStackView structure. Use horizontal alignment.

Then position this StackView you created.

Comment: Okay, i was thinking of the same but was wondering why does it reset the top Anchor constraint. Wondering what i'm doing wrong

Comment: After fixing the width and height it probably overlaps the "SearchButton" so it might be floating.

Or it can be this way because "SearchBar.trailingAnchor" and "SearchButton.leadingAnchor" are not assigned.

As I said, the most logical and effective solution here is the "UIStackView" structure.

Comment: I cant use the stack view, because i want to hide and animate the search bar by clicking on the search button, and when i toggle isHidden for the UIsearchbar the stack view resets layout

Answer (score 0):

Rid of the UISearchController and use a [UISearchBar](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisearchbar) instead.

```
let searchBar = UISearchBar()
let clearButton = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    view.backgroundColor = .gray
    setupSearchView()
}

private func setupSearchView(){
        
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    searchBar.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .darkGray
    searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    searchBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
    searchBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 2.0)
    searchBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    searchBar.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0
    searchBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
//        guard let customFont = UIFont(name: "Poppins-SemiBold", size: 14.0) else {
//            fatalError("""
//               Failed to load the "CustomFont-Light" font.
//               Make sure the font file is included in the project and the font name is spelled correctly.
//               """
//            )}
//        bar.searchTextField.font=customFont
        
   // set your search clear button
   clearButton.setImage(UIImage(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill"), for: .normal)
   clearButton.tintColor = .red
        
   let searchStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [searchBar, clearButton])
   searchStack.axis = .horizontal
   searchStack.distribution = .fill
   searchStack.alignment = .fill
   searchStack.spacing = 16
   searchStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
   self.view.addSubview(searchStack)
//        bar.isHidden = true
        
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            clearButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: clearButton.widthAnchor),
            searchStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 30),
            searchStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 30),
            searchStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -30),
            searchStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
        ])
        
   }
```

Comment: but getting rid of the Searchcontroller and using the UISearchbar would mean that i cant use the searchresultscontroller, search suggestions in the future implementations.